# MySQL using WITH clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQL to solve this problem on hackerrank.

**Why this code doesn't work**

```
WITH P_node AS (
SELECT DISTINCT P FROM BST)

SELECT CASE
    WHEN P IS NULL THEN CONCAT(N, ' Root')
    WHEN N IN P_node THEN CONCAT(N, ' Inner')
    ELSE CONCAT(N, ' Leaf') 
    END
FROM BST
ORDER BY N;
```

**But this code works?** I'm confused, can somebody help me?

```
SELECT CASE
    WHEN P IS NULL THEN CONCAT(N, ' Root')
    WHEN N IN (SELECT DISTINCT P FROM BST) THEN CONCAT(N, ' Inner')
    ELSE CONCAT(N, ' Leaf')
    END
FROM BST
ORDER BY N ASC
```

Comment: You have to select from P_node to use its column P_none.P.

Answer (score 0):

Correct syntax is:

```
WITH P_node AS (
SELECT DISTINCT P FROM BST)

SELECT CASE
    WHEN P IS NULL THEN CONCAT(N, ' Root')
    WHEN N IN (select P from P_node) THEN CONCAT(N, ' Inner')
    ELSE CONCAT(N, ' Leaf') 
    END
FROM BST
ORDER BY N;
```

Basically replace `P_node` with `(select P from P_node)` in `WHEN N IN P_node THEN CONCAT(N, ' Inner')`